# mysql running ubuntu 12.04 can't connect

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, xampp, mysql-error-2002

I am new to linux and I'm trying to install Mysql on a Ubuntu 12.04. (on the same machine)
When I type `machine@machine$ ./lampp start` it says XAMPP-MYSQL is already running.

But when I try accessing phpmyadmin or if I type `machine@machine$mysql -u root -p` I get the following error:

> "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"

These commands maybe helpful:

```
machine@machine$ sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 *:mysql                 *:*                     LISTEN      8401/mysqld
```

Comment: Perhaps xampp puts the socket elsewhere... can you connect with `mysql -h127.0.0.1 -u root -p` ?

Comment: yes it did connect. And I've also checked the **my.cnf** file. Will it be helpful if I moved it to **/etc/** ?

Comment: If you installed Xampp with relatively little experience, I wouldn't go altering configuration just yet until you're comfortable with the packages (at which point you probably won't need xampp anymore). Just remember that for code/phpmyadmin you can use 127.0.0.1 instead of `localhost` to use a TCP connection, and if you want to use the command line with more ease, create a `.my.cnf` file in you homedir, containing `[client]<newline>socket=/actual/path/to/socket`